# How to get the html object to pass it as a variable in angularj

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Sorry if it was already posted, but I can not find it and can not write the question clearer.

I am trying to get the instance of an html object and use it as a variable in angularJs, here an example to illustrate it

```
<div id="whatever" class="donotcare" data-ng-init=doSomething(htmlobject)>blabla bla</div>

$scope.doSomething = function(){
    console.log("the div object is there")
}
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is to get the div and pass it as a variable so I could get its id with angularjs, its content...

When you click, it is easy, just get the $event then on javascript get the currentTarget.  But what I want is it to run upon loading.
Hope you understand

Comment: just use `getElementById()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but like I said, I have hard time finding the right word to explain. let just say I do not have the Id, i want to pass the whole html object as a variable and access it in angular

Comment: How do you get this `htmlobject` initially (before passing to doSomething())? Are you querying the existing DOM tree using some selector or you create unbound DOM element?

Answer (score 0):

Made a little modification to my code. The point is that when interaction happens e.g. click and pass the event obj to the function.

---

Not sure what exactly do you mean. But below code may help you out:

HTML code:

```
<button id="whatever" class="donotcare" (click)="doSomething($event)">blabla bla</div>
```

Controller Code:

```
this.doSomething = function(evt) {
  console.log(evt.currentTarget);
}
```

Comment: I edited your answer to make the code cleaner and you should use `currentTarget` instead of `target`

Comment: I literally copied and pasted your answer and I got this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentTarget' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Decorator Directives-

1. It is used to change/add the functionality to the existing element.
2. Implement as an attribute and no template.
3. Link function is used to modify the html element and register the event. Scope or controller is not used.
4. Link function takes three parameter - scope, el (html element), attrs (attribute list for the element)
5. Scope.$apply should be used to start the Angular digest cycle to external jquery and html5 event.

In your case you can create a new Decorator Directives and use the below code in the link function to get the handle on body-

```
link : function(scope, el, attrs){
//you code will go here using $('body')
}
```

Comment: I did it at first but had to find something else since I can not use the "$compile"  module in directive link function

Comment: You can use Scope.$apply. It should be used to start the Angular digest cycle to external jquery and html5 event.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where `doSomething()` is defined, you can take one of the options:

**Option #1**

If you have `doSomething()` defined somewhere in the global scope, you can try to write your own angular directive `app-init` instead of `ng-init` and pass to it the function name that you want to call (in your case `doSomething`). This function will receive DOM element (html object, as you call it) and do with it whatever you want, for example alert the id.

```js
function doSomething(obj) {
  alert(obj && obj.id);
}

angular
  .module('app',[])
  .directive('appInit', ['$window', function($window) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $window[attrs.appInit](element[0])
      }
    }
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div id="whatever" class="donotcare" app-init="doSomething">blabla bla</div>
</div>
```

**Option #2**

If you have `doSomething()` defined in one of the parent scopes, you can do the following:

```js
angular
  .module('app',[])
  .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.doSomething = function doSomething(obj) {
      alert(obj && obj.id);
    }
  })
  .directive('appInit', function() {
    return {
      scope: { appInit: '&' },
      link: function(scope, element) {
        scope.appInit({element: element[0]})
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div id="whatever" class="donotcare" app-init="doSomething(element)">blabla bla</div>
</div>
```

More info on how to use `&` binding in directives may be found here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

---

**ngInit**

If you look into AngularJS [source code](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.6/angular.js), you will see that actually `ng-init` code does almost the same:

```
var ngInitDirective = ngDirective({
  priority: 450,
  compile: function() {
    return {
      pre: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$eval(attrs.ngInit);
      }
    };
  }
});
```